# Google Recaptcha using PHP to send to DB

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

Hello I am having trouble getting the captcha to work. I have my form being sent to my DB. I can submit the form even if the captcha isn't checked. I have the form being sent to another page that then send the content to the DB.

```
<form id="x" name="x"  method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" action="submit.php">
            <h3>Enter Comment Here</h3>
            <div class='col-sm-8'>
                Name:* <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Name" name="name" /> 
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>

            <div class='col-sm-8'>
                <textarea spellcheck="true" cols="50" rows="5" style='width:100%;' placeholder="Comment Here..." id='user_comment'  name="user_comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class='clear'></div>
            <br />
            <div class='row'>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="THIS IS MY SITE KEY">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class='padding-left-15'>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
            </form>
```

This is how I am submitting the content from the form.

```
<?php 
require("connect.php");
$sql="INSERT INTO comments(comment_id, user_comment, name, time)
VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[user_comment]', '$_POST[name]', NULL)";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}       
?>
```

I don't really understand how to do the server side check to get it working properly or where to put it. Anything will help.